# How to set custom column's datacontext to ItemsSource item type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I am trying to understand how the framework's default implementation manages to have the datacontext of an itemssource item. Specifically, when a DataGrid's ItemsSource is set (to for example a collection of Foo objects) and you define your columns within the DataGrid.Columns property, the DataGridTextColumn "Binding" property is expecting a property from a Foo object.

The following code might illustrate the issue better :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string FooDesignation { get; }
}
```

My very simple viewmodel containing the collection for my DataGrid. I then wish to use my own custom columns to add to the DataGrid's column collection :

```
public class CustomDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Text), 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(CustomDataGridTextColumn), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string) this.GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    private Binding _textBinding;

    public Binding TextBinding
    {
        get => _textBinding;
        set => _textBinding = value;
    }
```

The resulting XAML looks like this (in MainWindowView the datacontext is set to an instance of *MainWindowViewModel*)

```
<d:Window.DataContext>
    <x:Type Type="local:MainWindowViewModel" />
</d:Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FooDesignation}" />
            <local:CustomDataGridTextColumn Text="{Binding FooDesignation}" TextBinding="{Binding FooDesignation}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The *DataGridTextColumn*'s *Binding* property can be bound to the property of Foo (FooDesignation) without issue, intellisense also shows this property as an option.

My own *CustomDataGridTextColumn*'s Text and TextBinding properties however, show a designtime and runtime error when bound to the same FooDesignation property. Intellisense shows me my MainWindowViewModel's *Foos* property as option (which makes sense as apparently it did not inherit the Foo object datacontext).

My assumption is it has something to do with the fact that *DataGridTextColumn*'s Binding property is of type *Binding*, and is configured in a way to behave the way it does.

I couldn't find/understand how this is achieved. Can anyone shed some light on this? My goal would be to get the *Text*/*TextBinding properties to behave the same as the *Binding* property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ItemsSource` to any `IEnumerable` and the `DataGrid` applies the bindings of the columns to the visual elements (controls) that gets created in the columns' `GenerateElement` and `GenerateEditingElement` methods:

```
    protected abstract FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem);
    protected abstract GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem);
```

As you see, these methods accept a non-typed `object` which is retrieved from the `IEnumerable`. The actual property values are resolved using reflection as with all other bindings. The columns simply apply the binding to the generated element.

If you want to create a custom column, you should inherit from `DataGridBoundColumn` or any its children and use the existing `Binding` property as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However it doesn't completely answer my question. Even if I (correctly) inherit from DataGridBoundColumn, my own properties still won't behave the same way as the Binding property (i.e. automatically binding to the current item in the enumerable, even with intellisense support). Telerik's DataGrid also implements a DataMemberBinding property that behaves like the Binding property, so there must be something i'm missing to implement this the same way.

Comment: @GeorgeB: Behave the same way how? In Visual Studio? Are you using Resharper or something else ?